# While Loop Wont Break in Python

Tags: python, while-loop, break

I can't figure out why my while loop won't break to finish the hangman program. I've included the whole program to give you some context. It will print the game over message, but not the win message

```
import random
import os
import time

def playGame():
 wordList = ["dog", "bird", "chair", "computer", "elephant", "school"]
 letterList=[]
 underscoreList=[]
 guessesLeft = 6

 word = random.choice(wordList)
 #print(word)

 for letter in word:
  letterList.append(letter)
  underscoreList.append("_")
 #print(letterList)
 #print(underscoreList)

 while guessesLeft > 0:
  #os.system('clear') #clears screen
  print(underscoreList)
  print("You Have" , guessesLeft, "Guesses Remaining")

  userGuess = (input("Please enter a letter... \n>")).lower()
  if len(userGuess) != 1 or not userGuess.isalpha():
   print("Please Enter A Single Letter Only")
   time.sleep(1)
  elif userGuess in letterList:
   print(userGuess, "is there")
   time.sleep(1)
   for position, letter in enumerate(letterList):
    if letter == userGuess:
     underscoreList[position] = userGuess 
    elif '_' not in underscoreList:
     break
  else:
   print("Not In Word")
   time.sleep(2)
   guessesLeft -= 1

 if guessesLeft > 0:
  print("Congratulations you have guessed the word " , word)

 else:
  print("You Loser")


playGame()
```

Comment: It breaks the most inner loop. `for` in this case. And BTW four spaces indentation will make your code more readable and you will see such problems more easily.

Comment: Use  'for i in range(1,len(word))' not while loop

Comment: Ok but how would I then get out of the while loop?

Comment: Please try to fix your formatting, it's very advicable to indent Python code with 4 spaces per indent level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just have to move the elif to the beginning of the code. So now it checks before continuing the program.

```
import random
import os
import time

def playGame():
    wordList = ["dog", "bird", "chair", "computer", "elephant", "school"]
    letterList=[]
    underscoreList=[]
    guessesLeft = 6

    word = random.choice(wordList)
    #print(word)

    for letter in word:
        letterList.append(letter)
        underscoreList.append("_")
 #print(letterList)
 #print(underscoreList)

    while guessesLeft > 0:
    #os.system('clear') #clears screen
        if '_' not in underscoreList:
            break
        print(underscoreList)
        print("You Have" , guessesLeft, "Guesses Remaining")

        userGuess = (input("Please enter a letter... \n>")).lower()
        if len(userGuess) != 1 or not userGuess.isalpha():
            print("Please Enter A Single Letter Only")
            time.sleep(1)
        elif userGuess in letterList:
            print(userGuess, "is there")
            time.sleep(1)
            for position, letter in enumerate(letterList):
                if letter == userGuess:
                    underscoreList[position] = userGuess 
        else:
            print("Not In Word")
            time.sleep(2)
            guessesLeft -= 1

    if guessesLeft > 0:
        print("Congratulations you have guessed the word " , word)

    else:
        print("You Loser")

playGame()
```